# Java application monitoring via SNMP

Tags: java, linux, snmp

Java application and  monitoring  via SNMP.
I want to do possibilities to monitoring my Java application via SNMP.
I think, i should write to MIB messages from my application. Is it right? And how it usually implemented this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* you're running your application on JBoss server 3.2 or above, you can use JBoss's JBossSNMPAdapter (see this [link](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossSNMPAdapter) for more info).

The SNMPAdapter converts JMX notifications to SNMP traps, so this is probably only a good idea if you're already sending these from your application. Otherwise, sending SNMP traps directly from your application (See rsp's answer) is probably easier.

Answer (score 0):

To send SNMP traps from Java you can use [Westhawk's Java SNMP stack](http://snmp.westhawk.co.uk/)